# Transforming coordinates of one rectangle to another rectangle

Tags: c#, geometry, transformation, computational-geometry, coordinate-transformation

[image]

in the above image I have shown two rectangles

- **rectangle 1** whose x can vary from -900 to 13700 and Y can vary from -600 to 6458
- **rectangle 2** whose coordinate X can vary from 0 to 3000 and y can vary from 0 to 2000

**Also:** *rectangle 2* has its starting point at left top position(0,0) whereas *rectangle 1* has starting point( width/2, height/2).

**What I need to do**: to convert a point of *rectangle 1* to point of *rectangle 2* using scaling or translation.

So, what should be scaling factor for `x` and `y` coordinates in order to transform the coordinate of *rectangle 1* to *rectangle 2*?

Comment: Does the new point be on the 'same' spot within the next rectangle?

Comment: yes it would be on the same place

Comment: Even anyhow I want relative positioning among the points

Comment: duplicate with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536770/calculate-scaling-factor-for-converting-point1-x-y-coordinates-of-one-rectangl/20539498#20539498

Comment: MBo that is the same question which I had posted

Comment: Rectangle1 can range from -900 to 13700 but your origin is (width/2,height/2) you say?? This kind of suggests you are using 2 separate coordinate systems in the SAME rectangle. Your points inside the rectangle are specified from a different origin to the rectangle corners??

Answer (score 9):

If:

```
Rectangle 1 has (x1, y1) origin and (w1, h1) for width and height, and
Rectangle 2 has (x2, y2) origin and (w2, h2) for width and height, then

Given point (x, y) in terms of Rectangle 1 coords, to convert it to Rectangle 2 coords:

xNew = ((x-x1)/w1)*w2 + x2;
yNew = ((y-y1)/h1)*h2 + y2;
```

Do the calculation in floating point and convert back to integer after, to avoid possible overflow.

In C#, the above would look something like:

```
PointF TransformPoint(RectangleF source, RectangleF destination, PointF point)
{
    return new PointF(
        ((point.X - source.X) / source.Width) * destination.Width + destination.X,
        ((point.Y - source.Y) / source.Height) * destination.Height + destination.Y);
}
```

Comment: @Peter Duniho Thanks for the edit showing a C# example. (and yes, I know that commenting just to give thanks is a kind of rule breaking, but rules are written to make exceptions)

Comment: Has anyone had rounding errors using this method?  I am using this and I am finding that sometimes I need to Round Up to get the correct Point, and sometimes I need to round down.  Should a scaling factor be used?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
rectangelOne.x = rectangelTwo.x + rectangelTwo.width / 2;
rectangelOne.y = rectangelTwo.y + rectangleTwo.height / 2;
```

if your rectangleOne's pivot is correctly it should center automatically, otherwhise add this:

```
rectangleOne.x -= rectangleOne.width / 2;
rectangleTwo.y -= rectangleOne.height / 2;
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
float transformValue (float x,float  A,float B, float C, float D){

    return C + ((x-A) * (D-C)/(B-A));

}
```