# Get coordinates on mouse click in viewport wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to return the coordinates of mouse click in viewport. When I click inside the viewport, it is showing me screen coordinates (for example 480,650) but the range for my viewport is say (0,0) to say (10,10). How do I get the coordinates of mouse clicked to viewport coordinate system.
My xaml code:

```
    <Window x:Class="PathOptimization.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Geometries"
    xmlns:tool3d="clr-namespace:_3DTools;assembly=3DTools"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1000" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid  x:Name="grdView" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <Viewport3D x:Name="viewport" Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="button_MouseDown"   Margin="0,35,0,0">
        <ContainerUIElement3D>
            <ModelUIElement3D >
        ..............................            
            </ModelUIElement3D>
       </ContainerUIElement3D>
   <Viewport3D.Camera>
    <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,1,9"
    LookDirection="0,0,-2"
    UpDirection="0,1,0"/>
  </Viewport3D.Camera>
  </Viewport3D>
```

When I click on the screen inside the viewport, I am getting screen coordinates. How can I get coordinates relative to viewport.

```
private void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pointToWindow = e.GetPosition(viewport);
        Point pointToScreen = PointToScreen(pointToWindow);
        double x = (pointToScreen.X);
        double y = (pointToScreen.Y);
        MessageBox.Show(x + "," + y);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand... you are calculating `pointToScreen` explicitly and your question is how to **not** do this?

Comment: @nvoigt...I tried passing container to getposition method thinking I would get coordinates relative to container. But it is not happening. When I click the mouse inside the viewport, I want the coordinates of the location relative to viewport.

Comment: Then you should use `viewport` and not `grdView`, don't you think?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Ya I tried using viewport also but ended up in same result. Basically I could not relate camera view angle with the screen coordinates to convert them to coordinates in viewport.

Comment: So you want a 3D coordinate of your mouse? Mathematically that's impossible.

Comment: @ThomasWeller No I dont want 3D coordinate coordinate of mouse. Basically, I want to identify the point clicked by mouse in the viewport. When I click, it is giving me in screen coordinates (for example 650,480) whereas my viewport range is (0,0) to say(10,10). So, how should I get in this viewport coordinate system.

Comment: Slowly it becomes clear what you want. Please [edit] your question and include that information. Update your code to use `viewport`, because that's the correct thing to start with

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transforming coordinates of one rectangle to another rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630207/transforming-coordinates-of-one-rectangle-to-another-rectangle)

Comment: @ThomasWeller If it is rectangle to another rectangle where the dimensions can be related then I can change accordingly. But how to know the coordinates viewed by camera view angle and get the coordinates w.r.t. viewport. I am not getting how to relate the dimensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136835/discussion-between-codewarrior-and-thomas-weller).